# I want to change my "serial monitor" command to push button command for IR cloning project

Tags: arduino-uno, ir

```
void loop() {
  char data[6];
  int index = 0;

  delay(1000);  //Serial input seems to need some kind of short delay or the data gets screwed up.

  while (Serial.available() > 0) {            //Loop if there data on the serial line
    if (index < 5) {                          //Make sure we don't overflow
      data[index] = Serial.read();            //Load a character into the string
      index++;                                //Increment the index to get the next character
    }
  }

  data[5]='\0';  //Null terminate the string

  if (strcmp(data, "POWER") == 0){                //If the Arduino receives the POWER signal...
    Serial.println("SENDING SIGNAL!");
    for (int i = 0; i < NumIRsignals; i+=2) {         //Loop through all of the IR timings
      pulseIR(IRsignal[i]*10);              //Flash IR LED at 38khz for the right amount of time
      delayMicroseconds(IRsignal[i+1]*10);  //Then turn it off for the right amount of time
    }
  }                                         //Otherwise do nothing!
}

// This function allows us to PWM the IR LED at about 38khz for the sensor
// Borrowed from Adafruit!
void pulseIR(long microsecs) {
  // we'll count down from the number of microseconds we are told to wait

  cli();  // this turns off any background interrupts

  while (microsecs > 0) {
    // 38 kHz is about 13 microseconds high and 13 microseconds low
   digitalWrite(IRledPin, HIGH);  // this takes about 3 microseconds to happen
   delayMicroseconds(10);         // hang out for 10 microseconds, you can also change this to 9 if its not working
   digitalWrite(IRledPin, LOW);   // this also takes about 3 microseconds
   delayMicroseconds(10);         // hang out for 10 microseconds, you can also change this to 9 if its not working

   // so 26 microseconds altogether
   microsecs -= 26;
  }

  sei();  // this turns them back on
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? We aren't a code writing service.

Comment: Purav Vashisht, please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code, not just snippets.  Also note that your question is going to be closed pretty soon unless you edit it to include a clearly stated question.  Or at least a question.

Comment: `//Serial input seems to need some kind of short delay or the data gets screwed up.` - Wrong, wrong, wrong! Read this: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/

Comment: Please specify your question.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Your "question" just seems to be some code. The subject title doesn't really clarify what the question is.

Answer (score 2):

1. Identify the code which collects the characters from the serial port.  Then remove it.
2. Also remove the line of code which check to see if the correct character sequence was received.
3. Replace the above check with code that tests if a button has been press.

Note:

- Mechanical buttons bounce!
- And software is fast enough to see this as multiple button presses.

Avoid problems by going [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce) and learning how to connect buttons to an Arduino and de-bounce buttons in software.